# I get "cannot index into a non array" error although I have declared the variable 4 bits. Using Vivado to program NEXYS 4

Tags: arrays, verilog, xilinx

I am a beginner in verilog coding so all help is appreciated.

In my top module I call three modules. The slowclock slows the clock on board down to viewable speed. The counterten counts to 9 and then resets to 0. The other displays the number that is produced by the counter module.

My errors are as follows:

```
[Synth 8-1751] cannot index into non-array count1 
[Synth 8-1751] cannot index into non-array count1
[Synth 8-1751] cannot index into non-array count1
[Synth 8-1751] cannot index into non-array count1
```

My code:

```
module Clock(
output [7:0] SSEG_AN,
output [7:0] SSEG_CA,
input CLK
);

wire [3:0] count;

slowclock slwclk(CLK,Clk_Slow);

counterten sec(Clk_Slow,rc,count1);

displaycounter display(count, SSEG_AN, SSEG_CA, CLK);

assign count[0]=count1[0];
assign count[1]=count1[1];
assign count[2]=count1[2];
assign count[3]=count1[3];
endmodule

module slowclock (clk,Clk_Slow);
input clk;
output reg Clk_Slow = 0;
reg [31:0] counter_out = 32'h00000000;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    counter_out <= counter_out + 32'h00000001; 
    if (counter_out  > 32'h02F5E100) begin
        Clk_Slow <= ~Clk_Slow;
        counter_out<= 32'h00000000;
    end
end
endmodule

module counterten(
input clk,
output reg rc,
output [3:0] count
);

reg [3:0] tmp = 4'b0000;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (tmp == 9) begin
        rc = 1;
        tmp = 4'b0000;
    end
    else begin
        tmp = tmp + 4'b0001;
        rc = 0;
    end
end

assign count = tmp;

endmodule

module displaycounter (count, SSEG_AN, SSEG_CA, CLK);
output reg [7:0] SSEG_AN;
output reg [7:0] SSEG_CA;
input [3:0] count;
input CLK;

always @(negedge CLK) begin
        SSEG_AN = 8'b11111110;
        case(count)
            4'b0000: SSEG_CA = 8'b11000000; //0
            4'b0001: SSEG_CA = 8'b11111001; //1
            4'b0010: SSEG_CA = 8'b10100100; //2
            4'b0011: SSEG_CA = 8'b10110000; //3
            4'b0100: SSEG_CA = 8'b10011001; //4
            4'b0101: SSEG_CA = 8'b10010010; //5
            4'b0110: SSEG_CA = 8'b10000010; //6
            4'b0111: SSEG_CA = 8'b11111000; //7
            4'b1000: SSEG_CA = 8'b10000000; //8
            4'b1001: SSEG_CA = 8'b10010000; //9
            default: SSEG_CA = 8'b11111111; //default all off
        endcase
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `count` 4 bits with `wire [3:0] count;` but the error is about count**1**. As it is not declared it is being created as a 1 bit wire.

Just add `wire [3:0] count1;` to the top level module `Clock`

Comment: As its so common to either forget to declare a variable or make a typo, leading to the inferred 1-bit net for the name which is frequently not what you want, I suggest always using '`default_nettype none' at the top of your files. That way, you tell the compiler/synthesis tool to not do this 1-bit net infer and throw an error instead for unrecognized names.